# Cannot save/retrieve symmetric string with keychain, error -25306

Tags: swift, keychain

on iOS, not on OSX, cannot save/retrieve symmetric string with keychain, I have no issue using this code with

> kSecClassGenericPassword

but I'd like to add a more secure usage of keychain with

> kSecAttrAccessible: kSecAttrAccessibleWhenUnlocked

and

> kSecClass: kSecAttrKeyClassSymmetric,

```
 let query = [
            kSecValueData: data,
            kSecClass: kSecClassGenericPassword,
            kSecAttrService: service,
            kSecAttrAccount: account,
        ] as CFDictionary
```

maybe I have no clear what some keys are required for or with, but cannot understand it from the documentation, I also get error -25306 that I discovered related to errKCNoSuchClass which is not clear what class is referencing to. Some colleague told be something changed in keychain around iOS 15, but it seems to be something different.

```
   let stringToBeSaved = "c773c86d0e4a553349d329d6bb74e0a20dddc72f3f6b14f02258770bc879573d663d33f32167692fa1a2d1f85a9e51650956660f7398a94fce678c6c194d9ff1"

 

final class KeychainHelper_SymetricMetods {
    
    static let standard = KeychainHelper_SymetricMetods()
    private init() {}
    
    
    
    //MARK: kSecAttrKeyClassSymmetric

    func save_kSecAttrKeyClassSymmetric(_ data: Data, service: String, account: String) {

        // Create query
        let query = [
            kSecValueData: data,
            kSecClass: kSecAttrKeyClassSymmetric,
            kSecAttrService: service,
            kSecAttrAccount: account,
            kSecAttrAccessible: kSecAttrAccessibleWhenUnlocked, //‼️ mandatory?
        ] as CFDictionary

        let status = SecItemAdd(query, nil)

        if status == errSecDuplicateItem {
            let query = [
                kSecAttrService: service,
                kSecAttrAccount: account,
                kSecClass: kSecAttrKeyClassSymmetric,
                kSecAttrAccessible: kSecAttrAccessibleWhenUnlocked, //‼️ mandatory?
            ] as CFDictionary

            let attributesToUpdate = [kSecValueData: data] as CFDictionary
            SecItemUpdate(query, attributesToUpdate)
            print("was duplicated, we overwritten")
        } else {
            print("status: \(status)") //‼️ -25306 errKCNoSuchClass
        }
    }
    
    
    func read_kSecAttrKeyClassSymmetric(service: String, account: String) -> Data? {

        let query = [
            kSecAttrService: service,
            kSecAttrAccount: account,
            kSecClass: kSecAttrKeyClassSymmetric,
            kSecReturnData: true
        ] as CFDictionary

        var result: AnyObject?
        SecItemCopyMatching(query, &result)

        return (result as? Data)
    }
    
    
    func delete_kSecAttrKeyClassSymmetric(service: String, account: String) {

        let query = [
            kSecAttrService: service,
            kSecAttrAccount: account,
            kSecClass: kSecAttrKeyClassSymmetric,
        ] as CFDictionary

        // Delete item from keychain
        SecItemDelete(query)
        print("Deleted")
    }

    
    
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `kSecClassSymmetricKey` is a bit of a strange constant, as it describes, and I quote:

> A private key used for symmetric-key encryption and decryption.

Therefore, you are not able to store your own `SymmetricKey`, password or raw binary key as symmetric key under that key. You are however able to store your key *more restricted* as per your request, using the `kSecAttrAccessible` attribute on a `kSecClassGenericPassword`, as that key is just available for generic password objects.

```
enum SymmetricKeyStorage {
    static func save(_ key: Data, account: String, service: String) {
        var attributes: [CFString: Any] = [
            kSecClass: kSecClassGenericPassword,
            kSecAttrAccessible: kSecAttrAccessibleWhenUnlocked,
            kSecAttrService: service,
            kSecAttrAccount: account,
            kSecValueData: key
        ]

        var status = SecItemAdd(attributes as CFDictionary, nil)
        if status == errSecDuplicateItem {
            let updates: [CFString: Any] = [
                kSecValueData: attributes.removeValue(forKey: kSecValueData)!
            ]
            status = SecItemUpdate(attributes as CFDictionary, updates as CFDictionary)
        }

        print("Status:", status)
    }

    static func read(account: String, service: String) -> Data? {
        let query: [CFString: Any] = [
            kSecClass: kSecClassGenericPassword,
            kSecAttrService: service,
            kSecAttrAccount: account,
            kSecMatchLimit: kSecMatchLimitOne,
            kSecReturnData: true
        ]

        var result: CFTypeRef?
        let status = SecItemCopyMatching(query as CFDictionary, &result)

        switch status {
        case errSecItemNotFound:
            print("Item not found, status:", status)
            return nil
        case errSecSuccess:
            print("Item found, status:", status)
            guard let result else { return nil }
            return result as? Data
        default:
            print("Failed to query item, status:", status)
            return nil
        }
    }

    static func delete(account: String, service: String) {
        let query: [CFString: Any] = [
            kSecClass: kSecClassGenericPassword,
            kSecAttrService: service,
            kSecAttrAccount: account
        ]

        let status = SecItemDelete(query as CFDictionary)
        switch status {
        case errSecSuccess, errSecItemNotFound:
            print("Item deleted, status:", status)
        default:
            print("Status:", status)
        }
    }
}
```